# How do I add a separator to my list of terms with get_category

Tags: categories, list, wp-parse-args

I have this...

```
$args = array('child_of' => 3422 );
$categories = get_categories( $args );
foreach($categories as $category) { 
    echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all members in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> '; 
}
```

I can't find a way to add a separator between each term?

Comment: What is it you have now and what is the desired result? You can add a seperator via CSS also. Just add a `border-left` of `border-right`.

Comment: @Refilon That's not a true separator as it will occur outside the terms. A separator only appears within the terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the code that you're using your just going to get a list of words that are links to the categories.

You are facing two problems, adding the separator and also making sure the separator isn't added to to the last item.

You have a couple options:
With your code:

```
$args = array('child_of' => 3422 );
$categories = get_categories( $args );
$i = 1;
$separator = ', '; // Include a separator to separate the category
$count_category = count($categories);   // get total category value  to limit the separator for last
foreach($categories as $category) { 
    if ($i != 1) {
       echo $separator;
    }
    if($i< $count_category && $i!=1){
      echo '.';
    }
    echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all members in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> ';  
  $i++;
}
```

or you can do it using

`get_the_category_list( string $separator = '', string $parents = '', int $post_id = false )`

```
$args = array('child_of' => 3422 );
echo get_the_category_list (',' );
```

see more here on the [developers page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category_list/).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I'm not at all good with php... sorry.

Comment: well just replace your lines of code with mine.

Comment: i have edited the code now, can you try it once again.

Comment: The `get_the_category_list` option didn't work...

`<?php get_the_category_list( string $separator = '', string $parents = '', int $post_id = false ); 
$args = array('child_of' => 3422 ); 
echo get_the_category_list (',' ); ?>`

Comment: thanks @Gopalakrishnan18